# PC Management software (Workstations)

Tags: networking, inventory-software

What are some good PC Management programs for enterprise ?

I am looking for something similar to Microsoft Intune.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion [kaseya](http://www.kaseya.co.uk/) is a good alternative, i have used it in the past and found it to be a great system to work with

> Kaseya provides IT System Management Software for IT Departments & Managed Service Providers. Including Network Management Solutions & Asset Management