# What software can manage multiple PCs with software installation and updates?

Tags: windows-7

What software that can manage multiple PC with software for installation and updates at the same time? Thanks

[PC Management software (Workstations)](https://superuser.com/questions/300966/pc-management-software-workstations)

[Keeping up to date with updates?](https://superuser.com/questions/2403/keeping-up-to-date-with-updates)

[Package managers for Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/86462/package-managers-for-windows)

[How to keep all your 3rd party Softwares always updated](https://superuser.com/questions/182674/how-to-keep-all-your-3rd-party-softwares-always-updated)

Answer (score 1):

windows server 2012 with a good admin and some additional software.

Also, your forgetting virus and backup solutions!  Unless you have those planned for.

edit:  Depending on the number of workstations you could use SBS11 (Small Business Server), another option.... would be to invest your money in your workstations and buy macs, some small businesses are moving to a mac platform, the servers OS is dirt cheap, easy to manage and requires less maintenance.  Also note that the machines are easy to replace and service and usually hold up well.  Where are you located?  Do you have a solid internet connection?

Comment: @ben_m, i forgot also to ask if there is a free 3rd party software for this, in the middle east and we have solid internet connection , we have more than 100 workstations

Answer (score 0):

Fog server is the good option for installing OS and also take OS as image and push that image to another system via NIC(network integration card).and also manage that local system. Fog server is opensource application.